# Windows Batch File using xcopy. Prompts on screen for Y, N, or A

Tags: batch-file

I wrote a batch file to copy files from a network share to the C:\ drive.  When I have this file run automatically each day, it asks the user to respond Y, N, or A to replace files already in the directory.

I am trying to make this automatic as possible.  I would like for it to answer "A" for all.  Could someone please help me with the syntax to do this?  So far I have:

> @Echo off
>
> xcopy "S:\Files" "C:\Files" /e /i

Answer (score 3):

Use the `/Y` parameter, like:

```
xcopy asd1.txt asd2.txt /Y
```

Comment: I would like for all files to be replaced even if they currently exist.  Could I use a /A  ?

Comment: @furniturepro2012 the /Y replaces without the confirmation, the default is Yes for all

Comment: @furniturepro2012 - Type `help xcopy` from the command prompt and you will see all the available options and the descriptions. The `/Y` option will suppress all prompts and automatically overwrite any existing files. Learn to experiment (in a safe way of course). If you had tried this answer, you would have seen that it does exactly what you want.